# Determiner and article - Can we omit them if sentence becomes wordy

Tags: word-usage, articles, word-order

```
 There is no enrollment form, membership fee, and restrictions on the 
 frequency of use.
```

or

```
 There is no enrollment form, no membership fee, and no restrictions on the 
 frequency of use.
```

If we omit "**no**", does it change the meaning?

On a similar note:

```
 I have a blue purse and an indigo umbrella
```

or

```
 I have a blue purse and indigo umbrella
```

If we omit **a or an**, does it change the meaning/Is it gramatically correct?

Answer (score 1):

In the positive sentence, it does not significantly change the meaning.

In the negative sentence, if you only put the one "no", you should use "or" instead of "and":

> There is **no** enrollment form, membership fee, **or** restrictions on the frequency of use.

This mirrors the way OR, NOT, and AND work in logic:

```
(NOT A) AND (NOT B) AND (NOT C)
```

is the same as

```
NOT (A OR B OR C)
```

Correct language doesn't always follow the rules of mathematical logic, of course.